# Highlight listed texts into HTML based on predefined color mapping

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a script that highlights certain text using predefined color mapping.

For this case I want the tags from `myDiv` to be highlighted with their corresponding colors from tagColors object

```js
const tagColors = {
  "#tag": "#00ccff",
  "#tagAgain": "#ff0808"
};

const tags = Object.keys(tagColors).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
let text = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;

for (const tag of tags) {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(`\\${tag}`, "g"), highlight(tag));
}

function highlight(tag) {
  return `<span style='color:${tagColors[tag]}'>$&</span>`;
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  This is some text with #tag, #tags, #tagtag, #notListed and #tagAgain.
</div>
```

The problem is that `#tagAgain` gets highlighted separately: the `#tag` is #00ccff and the `Again` is #ff0808.

I did try changing the regex to `\\${tag}\\b`, but it doesn't highlight the `#tag` in `#tags`. I want it to still be highlighted if the tag is continued with other words (leaving the extra words to be not highlighted.)

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet, where it doesn't appear to be working at all.  Please double check you've shown the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about css? Here's your example and some styling:

```js
const tagColors = {
  "#tag": "#00ccff",
  "#tagAgain": "#ff0808"
};

const tags = Object.keys(tagColors).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
let text = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;

for (const tag of tags) {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(`\\${tag}`, "g"), highlight(tag));
}

function highlight(tag) {
  return `<span style='color:${tagColors[tag]}'>$&</span>`;
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = text;
```

```css
#myDiv span span {
  color: inherit!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  This is some text with #tag, #tags, #tagtag, #notListed and #tagAgain.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to `for..in` the array (`Object.keys()`). So the code fails since you get integer indices instead of tag names.

```js
const tagColors = {
  "tag": "#00ccff",
  "tagAgain": "#ff0808"
};

let text = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;


const tags = Object.keys(tagColors).sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length).map(escapeRegex).join('|');
text = text.replace(new RegExp(`#(${tags})`, "g"), (_, tag) => `<span style='color:${tagColors[tag]}'>#${tag}</span>`);

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/14098260
function escapeRegex(string) {
    return string.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  This is some text with <#tag>s #tag++, #tags, #tagtag, #notListed and #tagAgain.
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to change `in` to `of`, but I already did it in my tested code though. I was using `for (const tag in tagColors)` before but then I change it to be sorted from longest first because it didn't highlight tags that contains shorter tag.

Comment: @CluelessFish does my solution with the allowedChars works for you?

Comment: It works pretty much like my code. The problem is that `#tags` doesn't get highlighted as `<#tag>s`, it's just left not highlighted at all

Comment: @CluelessFish added `<#tag>s` to the snippet, works perfectly

Comment: Sorry but what I meant is `#tag` from `#tags` doesn't get highlighted. I wanted it to be still highlighted, leaving the `s` to be not highlighted. There seems to be a working solution using css anyways, but thank you for your answer as I find the regex escape to be useful

Comment: @CluelessFish finally understood what you wanted... fixed, enjoy. and you don't need CSS. if you find my answer useful you could consider to accept it with the checkbox